# Клавиша TAB в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть небольшая программа, простой блокнот.

Но возникает "микро-баг", когда я хочу перенести строку нажатием клавишы "Tab", то есть сделать горизонтальную табуляцию но вместо этого происходит переход на кнопку. Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Свойство `AcceptsTab`

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.acceptstab?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство `AcceptsTab` в окне свойств `text.Box`.